# How to define optional parameters in Puppet::Functions

Tags: ruby, puppet

I want to create a puppet ruby function with `Puppet::Functions.create_function`. Here i define some parameters. Some of this should be optional or should have default values.

```
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:'foo') do
  dispatch :bar do
    param 'String', :param_1
    param 'String', :param_2
    param 'String', :param_3

    def bar(a,b,c)
      puts "#{a} - #{b} - #{c}"
    end
end
```

param_1 and param_3 should be optional. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Optional parameters with default values need to be the final arguments. It would have to be 2 and 3, not 1 and 3.

Comment: But where i have to define the default values? In def or in dispatch part?
Can you provide an working example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it

```
  Puppet::Functions.create_function(:foo) do
    dispatch :foo do
      param 'String', :param_1
      optional_param 'String', :param_2
      optional_param 'String', :param_3

      def foo(param_1, param_2='default_value', param_3='default_value')
        puts "#{param_1} - #{param_2} - #{param_3}"
      end
  end
```

see here for an example https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/master/lib/puppet/functions/to_json_pretty.rb

Comment: Ok, `optional_param` does the trick. This is what I missed in my tests. Thanks a lot.